Unhandled Runtime Error when trying to using Next.js / React.js
I received this error when trying to implement a globe to my page. I'm getting the globe code on Aceternity UI. GitHub Globe
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: ReactSharedInternals is undefined

What I've done is checking the React version on package.json which initially looked like this
"react": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106",
"react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106",

So I found a stable version, and changed it to this:
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",

The error won't go away. Any help? I'm newbie to website development and have a little knowledge to look where the thing that I need to see. Any help will be appreciated!
